# Tiles generated from mbutil does not render using leafletjs

Tags: javascript, mapping, leaflet, tilemill, mbtiles

First I created a map using TileMill then export it as ".mbtiles" then using mbutil I generated tiles(.png) of that file.

Now, I want to use those tiles using leafletjs but it returns an error:
[image]

As I examine the file, it did not match.
[image]

What could be the wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([7.038218,9.017317], 13);
L.tileLayer(
    'cbr90013/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try

- Check your coordinates in setView(), they should be [LatLong](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview).
- In the output folder after calling mbutil, you should have a file called `metadata.json` which may be useful.  Check if it lists the `scheme` (either `xyz` or `tms`).  That will tell you the Y direction of the tiles
- You can also use this [Maptiler.com tool](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) to give you a visual on where the missing tiles show up on a Google Map.
- From the [Leafletjs.com documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tms), you may have to add the `tms` property.  The default is false, and since you don't have it, you can add it and set it to true.

Your LatLng coordinates did not match your missing tiles (e.g., 13/4979/6931.png), so there may be a mismatch there, too.

---

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([7.038218,9.017317], 13);
L.tileLayer(
        'cbr90013/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        tms: true
        minZoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks.So, what scheme should I use in generating tiles? xyz or tms?

Comment: You can check the options using `mb-util --help`.  mb-util also gives a description of scheme.

Comment: I used "tms" as my scheme in mbutil and in older version of leaflet you need to add `tms:true`, for the new you can set `{-y}` in the url.